# as3 how can I search in the vector

Tags: actionscript-3, search, vector

I can do the search in array with indexOf, but vector does not work

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

var characters:Vector.<String >  = Vector.<String > (["abcdef".split("")]);
trace(characters);

txt.restrict = characters.toString();
txt.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,search);
function search(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    var i:int = characters.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(event.charCode));
    trace("key press= "+String.fromCharCode(event.charCode),"indexOf search ="+i);
}
```

output

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
key press= a indexOf search =-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your vector is containing only one element, namely the array `a,b,c,d,e,f`. `"abcdef".split("")` returns an `array = [a,b,c,d,e,f]`. When you are using another `[]` around it, it is creating another array, i.e. `["abcdef".split("")]` is an array with length = 1 `[[a,b,c,d,e,f]]`. Thus your vector contains one single element, an `array = [a,b,c,d,e,f]`.

To solve this you need to remove `[]` in `Vector()` call.

```
var characters:Vector.<String >  = Vector.<String > ("abcdef".split(""));
```

Comment: 'To solve this you need to remove [] in Vector() call'
good answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Problem with `characters  = Vector.<String > (["abcdef".split("")]);` this statement.

It will store all letter at 0th location of vector like [0] = "a,b,c,d,e,f". But in your case that need to be store in different index like

[0] = "a"

[1] = "b"

[2] = "c"

.

.

[5] = "f"

If it so it will work. also why you are trying to restrict those value like a,b,c etc.